# iPhone toggle button using jQuery

Tags: jquery, iphone

Is there a jQuery pluggin for emulating an iPhone toggle button?

[image: iPhone toggle button]

Comment: Found a plugin: http://labs.engageinteractive.co.uk/itoggle/
I would still like to know of other options!

Answer (score 7):

This is a pretty nice, easy jquery plugin: http://simontabor.com/toggles/

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what is the expected effect, but I assume that You want a slider which covers blue 'On' and reveals grey 'Off'

My proposition:
http://jsfiddle.net/GzL87/1/

Answer (score 3):

Here you go buddy:

http://awardwinningfjords.com/2009/06/16/iphone-style-checkboxes.html

Comment: Out of the box this has a bug and does not work (at least the jQuery version)

Answer (score 2):

I took @Randomblue's solution and used it as my base for creating a more involved slider toggle that has full support for [ARIA standards](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/).  It is built on top of jQuery and jQuery UI.  I was required to have working ARIA support in IE9 and JAWS 14, and the out-of-the-box jQuery solutions have weird behavior in this regard despite purported support.

The solution is a simple jQuery plugin that turns a div with radio inputs into a slider toggle.

So given the HTML:

```
<div id="myToggle"
     class="slider-toggle-container"
     style="float: left"
     data-initialvalue="0"
     data-height="50"
     data-width="90"
     data-ballwidth="24"
     data-tabindex="undefined"
     data-speed="150">

    <span id="myToggleLabel" class="slider-toggle-label-text">
        Like this toggle?
    </span>

    <label for="leftInput">YES</label>
    <input id="leftInput" type="radio" name="enabled" value="1">

    <label for="rightInput">NO</label>
    <input id="rightInput" type="radio" name="enabled" value="0">

</div>
```

It creates a draggable, clickable, ARIA-compliant slider toggle.

The full code:  http://jsfiddle.net/reesbyars/JrVgt/

Answer (score 2):

I use jQuery UI plugin Switchbutton
Demo: http://naeka.github.io/jquery-switchbutton/
Source: https://github.com/tdreyno/iphone-style-checkboxes